# FTP Nautilus ( Ubuntu Filemanager ) overwrite File with empty content

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

I connect via ftp or fstp. When saving, it happens that an existing file is overwritten with empty content.

I use nautilus and I have not started any tests because it is an online shop that is in operation. (local machine Ubuntu 20.04, server machine / version not sure)

I recognised via winscp that the files were empty. I had the data locally, but when I saved it, it loaded itself to death and then saved a white page.

To fix it i had to import a 20h old backup and in the end connected via windows with windscp. Which was annoying for everyone, of course.

Do you know a way to prevent this from happening?

Unfortunately, I cannot give any more information, so I understand if there is no answer and the ticket is closed.

Comment: Check the logs on the server.

Comment: Hi Michael, im not running a server, it is just a normal PC. Or does Ubuntu have a log section? (Im new to Ubuntu)

Comment: As Michael mentioned, Check the FTP server logs to see what was uploaded. Start with providing more information in your question in regards to what the FTP server is, or at least how you connect. Figure out what and why will be needed to find a solution.

Comment: Hi, sorry i don't have root access to the log directory :S Thank you anyway :)